# Получить menu в android java

Tags: java, android, menu

Есть меню, объявленное так:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Заполнение меню; элементы действий добавляются на панель приложения
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Мне нужно изменять видимость одного из пунктов (search) этого меню (main_menu) при открытии соответствующей вкладки из этой вкладки.
Пытаюсь делать это так:

```
Menu menu = getActivity().findViewById(menu.menu_main); // (Error) Здесь ошибка menu
getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
MenuItem search = menu.findItem(R.id.search);
search.setVisible(true);
```

Но возникает ошибка (студия не принимает "menu" в строке "// (Error)").
Как мне получить само меню в строке, в которой возникает ошибка?

Answer (score 1):

Можно в фрагменте добавить в методе `onCreate` такую строку:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

и дальше получать доступ к меню которое было добавлено в активности:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu,MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Do something that differs the Activity's menu here
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.activity_menu_item:
        // Not implemented here
        return false;
    case R.id.fragment_menu_item:
        // Do Fragment menu item stuff here
        return true;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return false;
}
```

[вот подобный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24526783/android-how-to-access-actionbars-menu-items-in-fragment-class)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось таким образом:
Создаю ссылку на полученное в коде menu:

```
public static Menu menu1;

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu1 = menu;
    // Заполнение меню; элементы действий добавляются на панель приложения
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Далее ссылаюсь на статическую переменную menu1 в другом фрагменте.